# Rounding in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

When I execute this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
   Vt.Id, Vt.Description, 
   abs(Vt.Rate)as VRate,
   Sum(((itemprice * Qty) * (abs(Vt.Rate) / 100))) as VatAmount,
   Sum(itemprice * Qty) as NetAmount 
FROM
   BillItem1 as B1 
LEFT JOIN
   bill b ON b.orderid = b1.orderid
LEFT JOIN 
   ItemDescription ItD ON ItD.Id = B1.itemId 
LEFT JOIN
   VatType Vt on Vt.Id = ItD.TaxId 
WHERE 
   B1.IsActive = 1 
   AND B1.IsDelete = 0 
   AND b.date BETWEEN '11/09/2013 10:43:31 AM' AND '11/09/2013 10:43:31 AM' 
GROUP BY 
   Vt.Id, Vt.Rate, Vt.Description 
ORDER BY 
   SUM((b1.ItemPrice*Qty) - b1.NetAmount)DESC
```

the output is

[image]

and when I bind with data grid view its display following output

[image]

In `vatAmount` columns display lots of zero after decimal, so i want to reduce zero from grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enclose your VatAmount with `round(,2)`: `round(Sum(((itemprice*Qty)*(abs(Vt.Rate)/100))),2)`

Comment: you did `round(Sum(((itemprice*Qty)*(abs(Vt.Rate)/100))),2) as VatAmount` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to decimal type with 2 decimal points.

```
Select Vt.Id, Vt.Description, convert(decimal(20,2),abs(Vt.Rate)) as VRate,convert(decimal(20,2),Sum(((itemprice*Qty)*(abs(Vt.Rate)/100)))) as VatAmount ,convert(decimal(20,2),Sum(itemprice*Qty),)as NetAmount from BillItem1 as B1 left join bill b on b.orderid=b1.orderid
 Left JOIN ItemDescription ItD ON ItD.Id=B1.itemId Left Join VatType Vt on Vt.Id = ItD.TaxId where B1.IsActive=1 and B1.IsDelete = 0 and b.date between '11/09/2013 10:43:31 AM' and '11/09/2013 10:43:31 AM' Group By Vt.Id,Vt.Rate,Vt.Description Order By SUM((b1.ItemPrice*Qty) - b1.NetAmount)DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying value is the same anyway. How you display it is a matter of **formatting**. Formatting in SQL is usually unnecessary. Formatting should be done on the client that receives the data from the database system.

Don't change anything in SQL. Simply format your grid to display the required number of digits.

Comment: how i can change in grid.

Comment: I don't know how you populate your grid, so cannot really say without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the data displayed using the following code. This code causes truncation not rounding.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=sometable; //bind to datasource

DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.Format = "N2";
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Price"].DefaultCellStyle = style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert number in code side.

ex. :

```
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 256.583); // "256.58"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 256.586); // "256.59"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 256.58);  // "256.58"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 256.5);   // "256.5"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 256.0);   // "256"
//===============================
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.583); // "256.58"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.586); // "256.59"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.58);  // "256.58"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.5);   // "256.50"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 256.0);   // "256.00"
//===============================
string.Format("{0:00.000}", 1.2345);    // "01.235"
string.Format("{0:000.000}", 12.345);   // "012.345"
string.Format("{0:0000.000}", 123.456); // "0123.456"
```

In your case :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VatAmount">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# string.Format("{0:0.00}", Eval("VatAmount").ToString()); %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You can do this in Grid Binding event... OnRowDataBound event

Answer (score -2):

You can use Round function to get only required number of digits after decimal point.

```
double myValue = 23.8000000000000;
double newValue=Math.Round(myValue, 2);
```

Result : newValue = 23.8

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thank you, Could you please explain me, where i'm wrong.

Comment: Sure. What you did doesn't change the value at all. The double precision value `23.8000000000000`, when rounded to two digits, is still `23.8000000000000`. Now, `23.8050000000000` rounded to two digits is `23.8100000000000`, and `23.8040000000000` rounded to two digits is `23.8000000000000`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: i tried with different values. if value 23.8000000000000 rounded to 23.8, value 23.8050000000000 rounded to two digits is 23.8,if value 23.8060000000000 rounded to two digits is 23.81. in that case i don't know how my answer is wrong? please clarify me.

Comment: `23.8000000000000` rounded to two decimal places is still `23.8000000000000`. It may display as `23.8` or `23.80` or `23.800`, but it is still the same exact value. The same exact pattern of bits.